# How do I show virtual tree-view grid lines for nodes that don't exist yet?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, gridlines

I use SoftGem's VirtualStringTree in Delphi 7.

Is there a way to enable *full* grid lines (just as in a TListView)? I can only find `toShowHorzGridLines`, which only shows lines for current nodes, not anything in the empty space below, and `toShowVertGridLines`, which shows only vertical lines.

How do I show them in the empty space before items are added?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is an easy way to implement this without modifying `PaintTree` method since none of the node events cannot be fired because nodes whose lines should be drawn simply doesn't exist yet.

Here is an *dirty way* how to additionally draw the horizontal lines based on the lowest visible node. In fact it draws lines with distance of the `DefaultNodeHeight` value in the area filled by orange color in this screenshot:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
type
  TVirtualStringTree = class(VirtualTrees.TVirtualStringTree)
  public
    procedure PaintTree(TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Window: TRect; Target: TPoint;
      PaintOptions: TVTInternalPaintOptions; PixelFormat: TPixelFormat = pfDevice); override;
  end;

implementation

{ TVirtualStringTree }

procedure TVirtualStringTree.PaintTree(TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Window: TRect;
  Target: TPoint; PaintOptions: TVTInternalPaintOptions;
  PixelFormat: TPixelFormat);
var
  I: Integer;
  EmptyRect: TRect;
  PaintInfo: TVTPaintInfo;
begin
  inherited;
  if (poGridLines in PaintOptions) and (toShowHorzGridLines in TreeOptions.PaintOptions) and
    (GetLastVisible <> nil) then
  begin
    EmptyRect := GetDisplayRect(GetLastVisible,
      Header.Columns[Header.Columns.GetLastVisibleColumn].Index, False);
    EmptyRect := Rect(ClientRect.Left, EmptyRect.Bottom + DefaultNodeHeight,
      EmptyRect.Right, ClientRect.Bottom);
    ZeroMemory(@PaintInfo, SizeOf(PaintInfo));
    PaintInfo.Canvas := TargetCanvas;
    for I := 0 to ((EmptyRect.Bottom - EmptyRect.Top) div DefaultNodeHeight) do
    begin
      PaintInfo.Canvas.Font.Color := Colors.GridLineColor;
      DrawDottedHLine(PaintInfo, EmptyRect.Left, EmptyRect.Right,
        EmptyRect.Top + (I * DefaultNodeHeight));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

And here the result with constant and variable node height:

[image]

The glitch (the lines shifted from the left side) visible on the screenshot above is just a consequence of a dotted line rendering. If you set the `LineStyle` property on your virtual tree view to `lsSolid` you will see the correct result.

Comment: Now looking at the result, the rectangle is shifted. I'll fix it later on (I have to go now). But still it's quite dirty solution.

Comment: not dirty at all! thats actually pretty nice! thank you very much!

Comment: Phew, the line positions were correct. It was caused by dotted line rendering. However there was a bug. To determine the right bound of the line I was using the column with index `Header.Columns.Count - 1` what was wrong. If you had e.g. 2 columns and moved the second one to the first position, the index I should use (the index of the most right column) was 0, not 1 (what was `Header.Columns.Count - 1`). Now I'm using for that `GetLastVisibleColumn` what should be the right way.